# Fundamental solution of differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

I am working on a project on the semiconductor equations and I have arrived at the following PDE for electron transport with no electric field and initial carrier density $n_0$:
$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t} = - \frac{n-n_0}{\tau_n} + D_n\frac{\partial^2 n}{\partial x^2}$$

I have come across some literature saying this has solution 
$$n(x,t) = \frac{N} {(4\pi D_nt) ^{1/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{4D_nt}-\frac{t}{\tau_n}\right)+n_0$$

Where $N$ is the number of electrons/holes initially generated per unit area, $D_n$ is the diffusive constant for electrons and $\tau_n$ is the carrier lifetime. 
However working through I can't arrive at this myself and ideally need to understand the mathematics behind it.

If anyone could go through how this solution is reached it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's just differentiation of both sides, where do you get stuck? Also explain your notation.

Comment: Edited to explain some of the terms/constants. I want to know the steps taken to solve the PDE and obtain that solution, as I have only used the fundamental solution for homogeneous PDEs in the past.